# Discover WiFi P2p Devices and display them in FragmentList

Tags: android, permissions, wifi, p2p

I'm trying to discover WiFi P2p Devices and display them in a Fragment-List later on. The Problem is: It works fine on Android 4.4.2, but on Android 8.0.0 (OnePlus 3, Oxygen OS 5.0.1)it doesn't. I've already queried the necessary Permissions in the XML and checked them per requestPerissions. Where is the Problem I fail to see?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MyWiFiActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Main:

```
package com.example.mcorp.wifi_service;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.WpsInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MyWiFiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener, DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener{





private static final String TAG = "WIFI______DEBUG";
WifiP2pManager mManager;
WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
private boolean retryChannel = false;

public WifiP2pConfig mConfig = new WifiP2pConfig();

String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Cahnnel connects p2p, Receiver now notifies this activity about changes and updates accordingly manipulate wifi states
    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);
    //um richtige actions via broadcast zu empfangen
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    Button btn_server = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_server);
    Button btn_client = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_client);
    //Bei api >22 pemissions_abfrage geändert
    if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        Log.e(TAG, "Permission request gestartet");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS,1);
    }

    btn_server.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    btn_client.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}
//menu_main.xml mit buttons discover u enable
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);


}

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String[] permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Permission abfrage nötig");
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Permission nicht gegeben");
                return false;

            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
    this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
}

@Override//für device list fragment
public void cancelDisconnect() {
    if (mManager != null) {
        final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_list);
        if (fragment.getDevice() == null
                || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED) { // device aus fragment holen
            disconnect();
        } else if (fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE
                || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.INVITED) {

            mManager.cancelConnect(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(MyWiFiActivity.this, "Aborting connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyWiFiActivity.this, "Connect abort request failed. Reason Code: " + reasonCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}

@Override//connect nach device ausgesucht
public void connect(WifiP2pConfig config) {

    mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            //success logic

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            //failure logic
            Toast.makeText(MyWiFiActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override//für device list fragment
public void disconnect() {


    mManager.removeGroup(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

    });
}

@Override//für device list fragment
public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {

}

//Wegen implements Channel listener
@Override
public void onChannelDisconnected() {
    // we will try once more
    if (mManager != null && !retryChannel) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Channel lost. Trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //resetData();
        retryChannel = true;
        mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), this);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Severe! Channel is probably lost premanently. Try Disable/Re-Enable P2P.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { //Menü mit discover und enable wiFI direct
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_directEnable:
            if (mManager != null && mChannel != null) {

                //Zugriff auf Systemeinstellungen WLAN--> enable wifi Direkt
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable WiFi Direct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "channel or manager is null");
            }
            return true;

        case R.id.action_directDiscover:
            if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(MyWiFiActivity.this, R.string.p2p_off_warning, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_list);
            fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
            mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(MyWiFiActivity.this, "Discovery Initiated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyWiFiActivity.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public void resetData() {
    Log.e(TAG, "ResetData called");
    DeviceListFragment fragmentList = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_list);

    if (fragmentList != null) {
        fragmentList.clearPeers();
    }

    fragmentList.device_choosen = false;

}
}
```

The Class Used for Discovery:

```
package com.example.mcorp.wifi_service;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DeviceListFragment extends ListFragment implements PeerListListener {




private List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
View mContentView = null;
private WifiP2pDevice device;
public boolean device_choosen = false;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    this.setListAdapter(new WiFiPeerListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_devices, peers));

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_list, null);
    return mContentView;
}


public WifiP2pDevice getDevice() {
    return device;
}


private static String getDeviceStatus(int deviceStatus) {
    //Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Peer status :" + deviceStatus);
    switch (deviceStatus) {
        case WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE:
            return "Available";
        case WifiP2pDevice.INVITED:
            return "Invited";
        case WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED:
            return "Connected";
        case WifiP2pDevice.FAILED:
            return "Failed";
        case WifiP2pDevice.UNAVAILABLE:
            return "Unavailable";
        default:
            return "Unknown";

    }
}


@Override //
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    WifiP2pDevice device = (WifiP2pDevice) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    device_choosen = true;
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_server).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_client).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).showDetails(device);
    //getActivity() in a Fragment returns the Activity the Fragment is currently associated
}

/**
 * Array adapter for ListFragment that maintains WifiP2pDevice list.
 */
private class WiFiPeerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WifiP2pDevice> {

    private List<WifiP2pDevice> items;

    public WiFiPeerListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<WifiP2pDevice> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        items = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_devices, null);
        }
        WifiP2pDevice device = items.get(position); // Hier ausgewähltes Device drin
        if (device != null) {
            TextView tvDeviceName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_deviceName);
            TextView tvDeviceDetails = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_deviceDetails);
            if (tvDeviceName != null) {
                tvDeviceName.setText(device.deviceName);
            }
            if (tvDeviceDetails != null) {
                tvDeviceDetails.setText(getDeviceStatus(device.status));
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}

/**
 * Update UI for this device.
 */
public void updateThisDevice(WifiP2pDevice device) {
    this.device = device;
    TextView tvMyName = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_myName);
    tvMyName.setText(device.deviceName);
    TextView tvMyStatus = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_myStatus);
    tvMyStatus.setText(getDeviceStatus(device.status));
}

@Override
public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    peers.clear();
    peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());
    ((WiFiPeerListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (peers.size() == 0) {
        //Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "No devices found")
        return;
    }

}

public void clearPeers() {
    peers.clear();
    ((WiFiPeerListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 *  FEHLER com.google.android.finsky.wear.ap.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null} bei API26 8.0.0 jüngere api geht ??
 *
 *  channel '4273b3d8 com.example.mcorp.wifi_service.MyWiFiActivity (s)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
 *
 */
public void onInitiateDiscovery() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Press back to cancel", "finding peers", true,true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                }
            });
}

/**
 * An interface-callback for the activity to listen to fragment interaction
 * events.
 */
public interface DeviceActionListener { // aufruf der methoden in UI!?

    void cancelDisconnect();

    void connect(WifiP2pConfig config);

    void disconnect();

    void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device);
}

}
```

LogCat: Error without Filter (No Errors when Show Only selected Application is choosen)

```
    01-10 14:59:11.946 5427-13173/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl2128893066.tmp: No such file or directory
01-10 14:59:12.028 22711-22731/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
01-10 14:59:12.070 22711-22731/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
01-10 14:59:12.080 7224-7224/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: Next Tag=services
01-10 14:59:12.081 7224-7224/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: 1invalidateCache:WriteServiceStateToFile
01-10 14:59:12.081 7224-7224/? E/RegisteredServicesCache:  Writing service state Data Always
01-10 14:59:12.125 2102-2122/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
01-10 14:59:12.130 555-555/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: hint lookup failed
01-10 14:59:12.131 5618-8577/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
01-10 14:59:12.134 5618-8577/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: gIOPHAl initialized
01-10 14:59:12.134 5618-8577/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: gIOPHAl calling iopstart
01-10 14:59:12.134 554-554/? E/ANDR-IOP: IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = com.example.mcorp.wifi_service pid = -1
01-10 14:59:12.134 554-624/? E/ANDR-IOP: is_in_recent_list is TRUE
01-10 14:59:12.135 554-624/? E/ANDR-IOP: io prefetch is deactivate
01-10 14:59:12.152 555-555/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: hint lookup failed
01-10 14:59:12.153 5618-8577/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
01-10 14:59:12.153 5618-8577/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: gIOPHAl initialized
01-10 14:59:12.153 5618-8577/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: gIOPHAl calling iopstart
01-10 14:59:12.153 554-554/? E/ANDR-IOP: IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = com.example.mcorp.wifi_service pid = 26879
01-10 14:59:12.153 554-624/? E/ANDR-IOP: io prefetch Capture is deactivated 
01-10 14:59:12.215 2102-2122/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
01-10 14:59:12.375 26211-26211/? E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.ap.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
01-10 14:59:12.403 7136-2397/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
01-10 14:59:12.448 7136-8785/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.google.android.talk/com.google.android.apps.hangouts.concurrent.impl.GcmTriggeredNotifier{u=0 tag="network_connectivity_wakeup:persisted" trigger=window{start=259135s,end=259136s,earliest=-14479660s,latest=-14479659s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-14738795s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=SOURCE_UNKNOWN-0}
01-10 14:59:12.507 555-555/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: hint lookup failed
01-10 14:59:12.507 546-546/? E/QCOM PowerHAL: Failed to acquire lock.

01-10 14:59:12.561 547-547/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendEnableReq:sensor(android.sensor.proximity) Sending enable to svc no:21
01-10 14:59:12.570 547-952/? E/qti_sensors_hal: reportSingleEvent: prox data: 5.000305 raw:44.000000 2988955392.000000 SAM TS: 4186367965 HAL TS:783114607762662 elapsedRealtimeNano:783132994026412

01-10 14:59:12.714 2517-2517/? E/ContentDetectionService: updateSceneDetectionState() - No SceneDetector
01-10 14:59:12.759 5618-10338/? E/DeviceKeyHandler: receive keyguard done, process gesture action
01-10 14:59:12.821 26879-26879/com.example.mcorp.wifi_service E/WIFI______DEBUG: Permission abfrage nötig
01-10 14:59:12.869 5537-6394/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: fpc_wait_finger_up FPC_LIB_FINGER_LOST
01-10 14:59:12.869 5537-6394/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: do_home fpc_wait_finger_up before do HOME ,status 0 
01-10 14:59:12.869 5537-6394/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: fpc_wait_finger_down_for_home_12_zone  -4
01-10 14:59:12.869 5537-6394/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: do_home  -4 canceled 00
01-10 14:59:12.876 547-547/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendCancel:sensor(com.oneplus.sensor.pocket) Sending cancel to svc no:31
01-10 14:59:12.878 5537-6394/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: do_home  sendCancel:sensor(android.sensor.proximity) Sending cancel to svc no:21
01-10 14:59:14.142 555-606/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: updated /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/../../../clkscale_enable with 1
                                                       return value 2
01-10 14:59:14.151 555-606/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to reset optimization [3, 0]
01-10 14:59:14.636 5618-7128/? E/JobSchedulerService: jobid:20536
                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Same jobid in systemuid.
                                                          at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService.scheduleAsPackage(JobSchedulerService.java:710)
                                                          at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService$JobSchedulerStub.schedule(JobSchedulerService.java:1904)
                                                          at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)
                                                          at com.android.server.backup.FullBackupJob.schedule(FullBackupJob.java:52)
                                                          at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$4.run(BackupManagerService.java:5417)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
01-10 14:59:22.892 5427-13173/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1894885616.tmp: No such file or directory
01-10 14:59:22.961 2102-2122/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
01-10 14:59:22.962 22711-22731/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
01-10 14:59:23.098 7224-7224/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: Next Tag=services
01-10 14:59:23.098 7224-7224/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: 1invalidateCache:WriteServiceStateToFile
01-10 14:59:23.098 7224-7224/? E/RegisteredServicesCache:  Writing service state Data Always
01-10 14:59:23.116 7136-2397/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
01-10 14:59:23.149 22711-22731/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
01-10 14:59:23.192 2102-2122/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
01-10 14:59:23.322 26211-26211/? E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.ap.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
01-10 14:59:23.404 7136-2397/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
01-10 14:59:23.418 26211-26211/? E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.ap.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
01-10 14:59:23.452 7136-8785/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.google.android.talk/com.google.android.apps.hangouts.concurrent.impl.GcmTriggeredNotifier{u=0 tag="network_connectivity_wakeup:persisted" trigger=window{start=259135s,end=259136s,earliest=-14479671s,latest=-14479670s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-14738806s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=SOURCE_UNKNOWN-0}
01-10 14:59:25.584 5618-7128/? E/JobSchedulerService: jobid:20536
                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Same jobid in systemuid.
                                                          at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService.scheduleAsPackage(JobSchedulerService.java:710)
                                                          at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService$JobSchedulerStub.schedule(JobSchedulerService.java:1904)
                                                          at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)
                                                          at com.android.server.backup.FullBackupJob.schedule(FullBackupJob.java:52)
                                                          at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$4.run(BackupManagerService.java:5417)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
01-10 14:59:27.142 555-606/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: updated /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/../../../clkscale_enable with 1
                                                       return value 2
01-10 14:59:28.208 555-555/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: hint lookup failed
01-10 14:59:29.540 555-606/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: updated /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/../../../clkscale_enable with 1
                                                       return value 2
01-10 14:59:31.736 555-606/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: updated /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/../../../clkscale_enable with 1
                                                       return value 2
01-10 14:59:37.792 25086-25086/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
01-10 14:59:37.815 555-606/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: updated /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/../../../clkscale_enable with 1
                                                       return value 2
01-10 14:59:43.133 5499-5499/? E/wificond: Received error messsage: Device or resource busy
01-10 14:59:43.133 5499-5499/? E/wificond: NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN failed
01-10 14:59:43.133 5618-6136/? E/WificondScannerImpl: Failed to start scan, freqs=null
01-10 14:59:51.242 5618-6139/? E/SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: getNetwork got null network
01-10 14:59:51.242 5618-6139/? E/SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: Failed to retrieve network object for 2
```

That's it

Comment: post logs cat messages

Comment: edited the Post, added LogCat

Comment: did you find the problem ?